# SQL statement joining Oracle and MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, join, remote-server

I never seen this, but is it possible to have one SQL call join data from Oracle and SQl Server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes- both Oracle and SQL Server support the linked server concept.  That allows you to reference the other server using a 4 part name.  For example:

```
select  *
from    LocalDb.Schema.Table
cross join
        OracleLinkedServer.RemoteDb.RemoteSchema.RemoteTable
```

Comment: does MySQL support the linked server concept?

Comment: @bmw0128: I think MySQL has a little used feature called Federated Storage, but it only works with other MySQL servers.  SQL Server can link to MySQL, see http://www.packtpub.com/article/mysql-linked-server-on-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 13):

Yes, Oracle and SQL Server both have functionality that allows to connect to other databases, including different vendors.  In Oracle terminology, it's a [database link](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/statements_5005.htm) instance while on SQL Server it's called a [Linked Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213778%28SQL.80%29.aspx) instance.

The syntax to reference the instance is different between Oracle and SQL Server though.  IE:

### Oracle:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM table_name@database_link_instance t
```

### SQL Server:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM linked_server_instance_name.database_name.schema_name.table_name t
```

### does MySQL support the linked server concept?

No, the closest MySQL has is the FEDERATED engine, which is only for connecting to remote MySQL instances.

### PostgreSQL?

PostgreSQL has [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html).  Last time I looked at dblink (pre-v9 release), it only could connect to other PostgreSQL instances.