# SQL Cross Server Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, join

Is it possible to do **cross-server Joins** (if the databases are on different servers, e. g. SQL Server and Oracle)? If yes, which database Servers allows cross-database joins?

Is it possible to do **cross-server Joins** in *SQL Server* or *Oracle*? Can we join Oracle database with SQL Server database? How can it be done?

Comment: I can't speak for Oracle, but from SQL Server, yes you can query other server's using Linked Servers. Note, however, that cross-**server** queries are not the best performers.

Comment: Maybe you could connect with two different connections, and interprete the databases with a 3rd party language (i.e. python, php etc...)

Comment: better way might be to use an utility which fetches data from source server and inserts them on target server

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too broad, but Lamu has the right answer for ad hoc queries which is a linked server (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2015/07/31/how-to-get-up-and-running-with-oracle-and-linked-servers/).

Comment: Also, note, what you're asking to do here is not a "Cross database" query. A Server will be hosting many databases, and querying 2 of those in the same query is a trivial task (i.e. in SQL Server `SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.Table1 T1 JOIN DB2.dbo.Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID`). What you are asking about are **Cross-Server** queries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL statement joining Oracle and MS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992573/sql-statement-joining-oracle-and-ms-sql-server)

Comment: @Larnu Why performance is not good for cross server joins?

Answer (score 2):

it is possible that you can join multiple tables on Different Databases on the Same server or different server in MS SQL Server.

If both databases are on the same server you can just join like this

```
SELECT
*
FROM [Database1].[Schema].[TableA] A
JOIN [Database2].[Schema].[TableB] B
ON A.Key = B.Key
```

If they are on different servers or different SQL instances on the same server machine, You can either use a Linked Server or a Bridge Query(OPENDATASOURCE).

To use Linked Server, first, you need to add a linked server connection

Refer this [Article](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-create-and-configure-a-linked-server-in-sql-server-management-studio/) to know how to add the linked server.

Once you have configured Linked server you can Query the Tables like this

```
SELECT
*
FROM [ServerName1].[Database1].[Schema].[TableA] A
JOIN [ServerName2].[Database2].[Schema].[TableB] B
ON A.Key = B.Key
```

or you can use the opendatasource

```
SELECT
    * FROM TableA A
JOIN OPENDATASOURCE (
   'SQLNCLI', -- or SQLNCLI
   'Data Source=OtherServer\InstanceName;Catalog=RemoteDB;User ID=SQLLogin;Password=Secret;').RemoteDB.dbo.SomeTable B
ON A.KEY = B.KEY
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you can,

> [STackover post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992573/sql-statement-joining-oracle-and-ms-sql-server)
>
> Yes- both Oracle and SQL Server support the linked server concept.
>   That allows you to reference the other server using a 4 part name. For
>   example:
>
> select  * from    LocalDb.Schema.Table cross join
>           OracleLinkedServer.RemoteDb.RemoteSchema.RemoteTable

**As a side note I googled `cross-database Joins in SQL Server or Oracle` and the first result was the duplicate stack overflow post. Please attempt to answer the question yourself before posting**